# Importing DialogFlow v1 agent fails

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to update a DialogFlow agent from v1 to v2 following guidance at [this page](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide#migrate_agents_using_fulfillment_or_dialogflow_api_with_integrations).

I've exported the agent, but when I attempt to import that file into a new agent, I get this error:

> Errors in 'Get Date' intent: If you want to enable a rich message
>   element or add a simple response, "Use response from the DEFAULT tab
>   as the first response" toggle should be enabled.

When I compare the "Get Date" intent file in the ZIP to other intents in the ZIP, I don't see anywhere to set this value.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this line in the "Get Date.json" file:

```
"defaultResponsePlatforms": {},
```

had to be adjusted to be:

```
"defaultResponsePlatforms": {
    "google": true
},
```

Of all the intents in the agent, only two were marked as errors on the import and had to have this setting added. This is only needed because the "Google Assistant integration" was turned on.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, you should try updating pip version and reinstalling `dialogflow_v2` library with the following command in terminal or command prompt:

pip install --upgrade pip
pip install dialogflow==2.0.0

Note that the version of `dialogflow` must be 2.0.0, due to the newer version of this library